# Disabling button state from other method

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to python and tkinter, so am having trouble with enabling button states from another method, like so:

```
def init():
 p1Buzz = Button(root, text = "P1 BUZZ", command = buzzed)
 p1A = Button(root, text = "A")
 p1A.config(state='disabled')

def buzzed():
 #how can you enable p1A here again
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use `class` & then with the help of `self` you can call `p1A` & set its state to `normal` or just make it `Global`(not recommended) & then set to `normal`. I have made a sample program for you:

```
class Abc:

    def __init__(self,root):
        p1Buzz = Button(root, text = "P1 BUZZ", command = self.buzzed)
        p1Buzz.pack()
        self.p1A = Button(root, text = "A")
        self.p1A.config(state='disabled')
        self.p1A.pack()

    def buzzed(self):
        self.p1A.config(state='normal')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    myapp = Abc(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Or using `global`:

```
from Tkinter import *
p1A=Button

def init(root):
    global p1A
    p1Buzz = Button(root, text = "P1 BUZZ", command = buzzed)
    p1Buzz.pack()
    p1A = Button(root, text = "A")
    p1A.config(state='disabled')
    p1A.pack()

def buzzed():
    p1A.config(state='normal')

root=Tk()
init(root)
root.mainloop()
```